# How to publish blossom template to magnolia Public module

Tags: java, spring-mvc, magnolia

For few days I'm trying to start using magnolia CMS with blossom module but I struggle with it, and spend many hours without any progress.
I'm working on blossom example from http://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Blossom+module#GettingStarted  and running it from eclipse with `org.mortbay.jetty:maven-jetty-plugin:6.1.21:run-war` plugin with 5.2.4 Magnolia version and I'm running it on port 9999. I have also installed this same version of full magnolia on tomcat instance on default 8080 port.
And the problem starts when I want to publish the page from my blossom module ( the one on 9999 port) to Public Magnolia ( working on 8080). I can do it and I can also publish the templates placed in Configuration->Server->Install->mgnl-files. But once I do it, the templates on the Public are marked as red ( red dot) and when I'm trying to run the page I'm getting following error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   info.magnolia.rendering.engine.RenderException:
>   info.magnolia.registry.RegistrationException: No template definition
>   registered for id: blossomSampleModule:pages/main
>   info.magnolia.module.cache.filter.CacheFilter.doFilter(CacheFilter.java:165)
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:58)
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:80)
>   info.magnolia.cms.i18n.I18nContentSupportFilter.doFilter(I18nContentSupportFilter.java:73)

I have to mention that I have placed blossom jar into the public and author domain but no blossom module appears on the Configuration->modules list. It appeared there only after publishing it from my dev instance ( the one on 9999 port) to public ( on 8080)and it's marked on green while all others are on red.

Could you please advice me what I'm doing wrong or what I have missed ?

Regards

Jan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, you forgot to copy your blossom module to public instance as well. Blossom templates are generated dynamically from spring annotated java files, so jar file needs to exist on both instances.

HTH,
Jan

Comment: Thank you, you ware right. Do you know about any manual for blossom and spring security? I have to say that information from magnolia cms pages are not giving the clear view ...

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. You can add spring security for part (or whole of) your public site by simply inserting security filter in the filter chain (either in Magnolia itself or in your web.xml). If you want to do something more special like use Spring to authenticate users logging into Magnolia itself or to use spring to completely manage users, you better search magnolia forum for posts of people who have done the same with different authorisation and authentication systems.

Comment: Thnka you one more time. It seems that you are an expert in magnolia ;). I have posted new question regarding ss + blossom. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24714539/magnolia-cms-with-blossom-spring-security.